# Speeding up sparse FFT computations

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm hoping someone can review my code below and offer hints how to speed up the section between tic and toc. The function below attempts to perform an IFFT faster than Matlab's built-in function since (1) almost all of the fft-coefficient bins are zero (i.e. `10` to `1000` bins out of `10M` to `300M` bins are non-zero), and (2) only the central third of the IFFT results are retained (the first and last third are discarded -- so no need to compute them in the first place).

The input variables are:

```
fftcoef = complex fft-coef 1D array (10 to 1000 pts long)
bins = index of fft coefficients corresponding to fftcoef (10 to 1000 pts long)
DATAn = # of pts in data before zero padding and fft (in range of 10M to 260M)
FFTn = DATAn + # of pts used to zero pad before taking fft (in range of 16M to 268M) (e.g. FFTn = 2^nextpow2(DATAn))
```

Currently, this code takes a few orders of magnitude longer than Matlab's `ifft` function approach which computes the entire spectrum then discards `2/3`'s of it. For example, if the input data for fftcoef and bins are `9x1` arrays (i.e. only `9` complex fft coefficients per sideband; `18` pts when considering both sidebands), and `DATAn=32781534`, `FFTn=33554432` (i.e. `2^25`), then the ifft approach takes `1.6` seconds whereas the loop below takes over `700` seconds.

I've avoided using a matrix to vectorize the nn loop since sometimes the array size for fftcoef and bins could be up to `1000` pts long, and a `260Mx1K` matrix would be too large for memory unless it could be broken up somehow.

Any advice is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
function fn_fft_v1p0(fftcoef, bins, DATAn, FFTn)

fftcoef = [fftcoef; (conj(flipud(fftcoef)))];     % fft coefficients
bins = [bins; (FFTn - flipud(bins) +2)];          % corresponding fft indices for fftcoef array

ttrend = zeros( (round(2*DATAn/3) - round(DATAn/3) + 1), 1); % preallocate

start = round(DATAn/3)-1;

tic;
for nn = start+1 : round(2*DATAn/3)  % loop over desired time indices
  % sum over all fft indices having non-zero coefficients
  arg = 2*pi*(bins-1)*(nn-1)/FFTn;
  ttrend(nn-start) = sum( fftcoef.*( cos(arg) + 1j*sin(arg)); 
end
toc;

end
```

Comment: See http://www.fftw.org/pruned.html for an analysis of the potential savings.  It may not be worth it.

Comment: You're looking at `length(bins)*(2*DATAn/3)` operations, better than `DATAn*lg(DATAn)` for the FFT approach if `2*length(bins)/3 > lg(DAtan)` (since FFTW handles non-power-of-2 transform sizes, I'm ignoring the zero-padding).  For the case of 10 bins and 2^25 output points, that's '20/3 > 25', a potential factor of 3 improvement.  As soon as you get to 75 FFT coeffs, you've lost the advantage.  And you have to code the algorithm in C and maintain it.

Comment: Thanks mtrw, I reviewed the link above a few days ago. It originally gave me hope because it states: "Because of this, I would not recommend bothering to consider a pruned 1d FFT unless you want 1% of the outputs or fewer (and/or if 1% or fewer of your inputs are nonzero)." In my case, less than 0.00001% of my input (coefficients to IDFT) are nonzero. I think this should be the dominant reason for increase in speed, rather than the factor of 3 improvement you cite above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that Matlab uses a compiled fft library (http://www.fftw.org/) for its fft functions, which besides operating much faster then a Matlab script, it is well optimized for many use-cases. So a first step might be writing your code in c/c++ and compiling it as a mex file you can use within Matlab. That will surely speed up your code at least an order of magnitude (probably more).

Besides that, one simple optimization you can do is by considering 2 things:

1. You assume your time series is real valued, so you can use the symmetry of the fft coeffs.
2. Your time series is typically much longer then your fft coeffs vector, so it is better to iterate over bins instead of time points (thus vectorizing the longer vector).

These two points are translated to the following loop:

```
nn=(start+1 : round(2*DATAn/3))';
ttrend2 = zeros( (round(2*DATAn/3) - round(DATAn/3) + 1), 1);
tic;
for bn = 1:length(bins)
     arg = 2*pi*(bins(bn)-1)*(nn-1)/FFTn; 
     ttrend2 = ttrend2 +  2*real(fftcoef(bn) * exp(i*arg)); 
end
toc;
```

Note you have to use this loop **before** you expand `bins` and `fftcoef`, since the symmetry is already taken into account. This loop takes 8.3 seconds to run with the parameters from your question, while it takes on my pc 141.3 seconds to run with your code.

Comment: Hi Itamar Katz, excellent suggestions. I get similar numbers as what you show above for improvements using your suggestion #2 above and supplied code. I'm not sure though how to code your suggestion #1 above (to take advantage of symmetry). Can you describe more?

Comment: Oh, I see, you've already including suggestion 1 by including the "2*real" code above, and then I simply comment out the original two lines above for fftcoef=[...] and bins=[...]. Nice trick, it cuts the time in half. Then, there's no reason to expand bins and fftcoef.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The symmetry comes from the fact that for real valued data, the k'th coeff is the complex-conjugate of the (N-k)'th coeff, so you can sum each term and its conjugate to 2*real(...)

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! I've never worked with MEX before, is it simple to code up an example how it would look like?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is easy, but it is not too difficult either - depending on your experience, of course. Matlab has a good documentation on it, so it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a question/answer at [Accelerating FFTW pruning to avoid massive zero padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636327/accelerating-fftw-pruning-to-avoid-massive-zero-padding) which solves the problem for the C++ case using FFTW. You can use this solution by exploiting `mex`-files.